# Postfix deferred email - How to expire so bounce-back email gets sent back

Tags: postfix, email-bounces

My hosted email server is "Refusing to talk : 550" with my postfix server.
Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail all accepts them fine.  All of sudden hosted email provider decided not accept email from my server.  I dont really know why... i dont send out spam nor have large volumes.

Anyways, now they want me to get a bounce-back email.
All the email in question are in mailq (deferred)

How do I expire them so that postfix will send out "unable to send" to mail clients who sent them?

I dont want to delete them...

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `postqueue -f` as root to flush the entire queue; this will cause delivery to be re-tried.

If the remote server really reports a **550**, then the messages will *not* be deferred; they will be *rejected*, and your postfix server will instantly bounce them.

If this does not seem to be happening, make sure you do not have `soft_bounce = yes` set:

```
postconf soft_bounce
```

On any production server, the `soft_bounce` setting needs to be `no`.

Comment: well, messages are in deferred (not bounced).  I believe if I set "maximal_queue_lifetime = 30m", and do postqueue -f.  postqueue -f will flush and attempt to send/resend messages.  So in theory, anything in deferred(queue) longer than 30 min should get bounced.  What do you think?

Comment: I couldnt test out maximal_queue_lifetime setting.  For now, I've changed email server to relay, then did postqueue -f which did resend the messages.  (To be clear, this did not bounce messages.  Rather msgs were just relayed to a server which is accepting relay, which forwarded it to my hosted email server)

Comment: Please re-read the above: IF the messages are REJECTED with a 550 status, they will only be deferred IF you have soft_bounce set.

Comment: I didn't mean to question your statement, really...  But for my case, mail.log shows "Oct 31 18:04:14 mail1 postfix/smtp[15566]: 901241C0C81: host spam3.ihostexchange.net[66.46.182.94] refused to talk to me: 550 Connection refused"    And the same email was in mailq!   Anyways... Thank you for your help.

Comment: Then `soft_bounce = yes` on your server. This is ill-advised.

Comment: Just to update in case someone has same problem.  My ip was blacklisted on Barracuda database.  To remove : http://www.barracudacentral.org/rbl/removal-request

Comment: What about on a production server the ones where `status=deferred (connect to not-an-email-server.net[some-ip]:25: Connection refused)` and you want the user to receive and NDR because you know the server name they used is wrong?

Comment: i have a soft bounce email in the queue, it stays there for about 15 minutes (I suspect 1000s to be exact), which is the setting that can shorten/lengthen this 1000s?